# Searching the word occurance in coca (corpus of contemporary American English) including meaning

Tags: corpora, meaning

I searched for a word `inviting` in [coca](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)
and I got about 50 thousand usage examples. That's a lot of data.

I'm interested in, if there is some possibility to refine the search,
especially to search only certain meanings of the word (e.g. [attractive](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=inviting&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=)) or at least refine it by part of speech. If there is not such a tool, could you refer some techniques I can use to refine search and possibly implement (if I have the search result data)?

Comment: Meaning is contextual, so no, it is impossible in principle.

Comment: It's not wholly impossible, @AlexB. Most words in COCA are embedded in text, so there will often be enough context to decide among different meanings of a word. Obviously this can't be done 100%.

Comment: @ColinFine Exactly.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes but you have to manually examine your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use part of speech tags from **coca**, and there is a video explaining it on YouTube, see [The Linguistic Teaching Resources Hub.](https://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/resource/306/)

I am not aware of meaning annotation in coca.

Comment: That's right. **inviting.[j*]** or in their new syntax **inviting_j** will search for the adjective "inviting" as opposed to the verb. You can search for synonyms, but I don't think you can apply them to a word to select one meaning from others.

Comment: @OK This is certainly certain level of improving the search (the easier part, but great it works).

Comment: POS search is easy (and trivial). I believe the question was how to "search only certain meanings of the word."

Comment: @AlexB. From the original question *"or at least refine it by part of speech"*—this part of the question is answered, and I also note the absence of annotated word sense disambiguation in COCA. BTW, POS search is only trivial when it is already annotated.

Comment: It seems I overlooked that part, probably because I assumed everyone knew how to perform a POS search.